# Audio issue in 'node-wav-player'

Tags: node.js, audio, wav

```
play(file,index){
    try{
    const player = require('node-wav-player');
    player.play({
    path: path.join(appDir,'/Sounds/English/'+file[index++]+'.wav'),sync:true
    }).then(() => {
        if(index<file.length)
            this.play(file,index); //Recursive call 
        else{

        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        Log.ErrorLogging(error);
    });
    }catch(err){
        Log.ErrorLogging(error);
    }
}
```

While using windows, the gap between sound files will be greater than it is while using Linux or Raspberry Pi, why !?

What can I do ?!

Comment: Probably because [the player is OS-dependent](https://github.com/futomi/node-wav-player/blob/master/lib/wav-player.js#L92-L102).

Comment: Ok thank you but how can i solve it ?

Comment: You probably won't be able to continue using `node-wav-player` if that's an issue. Try looking for a library that supports streaming (e.g. running WAV files from a raw data buffer or a file stream rather than a string path)